# A better way to call child method from parent object

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, static

I wish to call a child method in a perent method from a map that givied from a child's method.  Basically the child gives the functions and the parent call them.

How can I use class child methods instead of static methods (see function 'login')? I try to call with pointers, but that didn't go so well.

And it is possible that the function 'optionsMap' would not create a new object every time the function is called, initialize the map only ones.

perent object:

```
typedef RequestResult(*handleRequestFunc)(IRequestHandler* self, RequestInfo what);
typedef std::map<unsigned char, handleRequestFunc> handleRequestFunc_map;

class IRequestHandler
{
public:
    virtual handleRequestFunc_map optionsMap() = 0;

    RequestResult handleRequest(RequestInfo requestInfo)
    {
        auto funcMap = this->optionsMap();
        auto code = requestInfo.buffer.getCode();
        auto func = funcMap.find(code);
        if (func == funcMap.end())
        {
            // error
        }
        else
        {
            auto funcPointer = func->second;
            return funcPointer(this, requestInfo);
        }
    }
};
```

child object:

```
class RequestHandlerFactory;
class LoginRequestHandler : public IRequestHandler
{
public:
    RequestResult static login(IRequestHandler* self, RequestInfo what)
    {
       LoginRequestHandler* myself = (LoginRequestHandler*)(self);
       // use myself
       return RequestResult();
    }

    // Inherited via IRequestHandler
    virtual handleRequestFunc_map optionsMap() override
    {
        handleRequestFunc_map returnMap;

        returnMap[0] = &LoginRequestHandler::login;  // function example
        return returnMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling member function pointers can get weird, but there should be no need for `static` functions. See if https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members offers any solutions.

Comment: Also look into [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). It's a bit heavier-weight, but it can greatly reduce the complexity and if you're sitting around for waiting IO transactions to complete in order to parse you probably won't even notice.